# How to Fire an event when mouse points to the top location of the window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, xaml

Hi I am developing an WPF applications where I need to show a `DockPanel` at the top of the window, but it will only show if mouse points to that location, (Exactly like Windows 8.1 Titlebar where if you point your mouse at the top, cross buttons and minimize buttons comes), If mouse moves out side of the Window and in other place the child Element `<StackPanel>` will cover up the entire window and will show data, but whenever the mouse points to the Top location of the UI, I should display the Header. I have attached an image, of my idea. Anybody can suggest something?

After a lot of Googling I found that getting the screen resolution and subtract from height and width of the window will give me the desire result. But I think this is not the ultimate solution, there must be a other way. [image: Header]

As suggested I tried this way

```
<Grid x:Name="gdMainWindow" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>

 <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="Transparent" Height="20" 
     MouseEnter="Dock_MouseEnter" 
     MouseLeave="dp_MouseLeave"            
 />

<DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="Black"  >
    <Image Source="Images/candle-blownout.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</DockPanel >
```

And in the `Dock_MouseEnter`

```
private void Dock_MouseEnter ( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
{
    dp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void dp_MouseLeave ( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
{
    dp.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

But it leaves that 20 pixel space at the top as white, the image doesn't adjust to the first row.

Comment: When I do this, I just throw like a 5px Rectangle across the top with a Fill=Transparent for hittestvisibility and a mousenter eventtrigger to make your menu visible over top of it, then on the menu have a MouseLeave trigger to collapse it again.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Rectangle x:Name="TopPart" MouseEnter="MouseEnterEvent" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveEvent" Fill="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" />
    <StackPanel x:Name="RestOfContent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2/>
</Grid>
```

It's a pseudo-XAML, so be careful that some of the properties might be named slightly different.

You create a `Grid` which has two rows, the first one of the dimension you want for your reactive top part, the second with the rest.

In the first `Grid.Row` you set a `Rectangle`, or another transparent element you'll just need to detect when the mouse enters or leaves, handling the events associated. The rest of your content will be placed in the same `Grid.Row`, but will have a `RowSpan` that will let it extend also the rest of the window.

If you have issues with this approach, I.E. the `Rectangle` overlaps to some content not allowing you to interact with it, you'll need to play a little with the `ZIndex` of the components, make also sure you're using this as the top part of your Window so that the `Rectangle` won't scroll down.

Comment: I'd ditch your rowdefinitions and handle it differently so there's not some big odd gap at the top. Maybe I should post one too

Comment: There shouldn't be a gap since both the elements start at the same Row (0)

Comment: Oh I got you, ya I didn't see that, I don't bother putting row=0 so when I see that just out of habit I assume it means another row. Fair enough :)

Comment: I tried to what you suggested, but its leaving that 20 px as white background. The image is not resizing to cover the first row.